# Building a JavaScript function to sort by object property

Tags: javascript

I need to use JavaScript to sort this sample data by either storeID number or the number of transactions:

```
transactionList = [
  {storeID: 102, transactions: 6},
  {storeID: 64, transactions: 22},
  {storeID: 295, transactions: 9},
  {storeID: 83, transactions: 4},
  {storeID: 96, transactions: 14}
];
```

Here is the function I was trying to build, where sort modifier is either "storeID" or "transactions":

```
function sortTransactions (modifier, transactionList) {
  return transactionList.sort(function(x, y) { 
    return x.modifier - y.modifier;
  });
}
```

So if I run this in console:

```
sortTransactions("storeID", transactionList);
```

I expected that my transactionList would be sorted. But the function just returns the initial value.

When I injected console.log(x.modifier, y.modifier) into the mix, it shows a value of undefined, so clearly I'm doing one or more things wrong here.

I had searched and found this to be the essence of what I was going for, but couldn't seem to translate that into my own working function:
[Javascript object list sorting by object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466356/javascript-object-list-sorting-by-object-property)

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Problem here `x.modifier != x[modifier]`

Comment: Write a good sort function: 1) data type, the result is different when you sort by number or string, for example, is 18>123 ? how about date sorting? 2)Usually I put a switch for desc or ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comment, if you want to access a property named 'id' of an object, you can do it in two ways:

```
object.id
object['id']
```

if the name of the property is stored inside a string though, you have to access like this

```
var modifier = 'id';
object[modifier]
```

Comment: @Contrapunctus_XIV you're welcome ^^