# Trying to sort an object array to display the top 3 items with the highest "score" element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a snake game which at the moment displays a ul on the html page with each player and their id, score, kills and length. What I'm trying to do is get that list to have a max of 3 items and going from the highest score, to the lowest.

It's just the sorting the snakes into another array with the top 3 being the ones with the highest score that's the problem. I can store every snake in the `topSnakes` array just fine, but after I do `topSnakes.sort` and try and read anything in it, it will come back as `undefined`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript object list sorting by object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466356/javascript-object-list-sorting-by-object-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
topSnakes=Object.values(snakes).sort((a,b)=>b.Score-a.Score).slice(0,3);
```

Sort after Score ( biggest first ), than take the first three elems. Your mistake is in the first loop, wich is unnecessary in my opinion...

Comment: its giving me the error of Snakes is undefined, should i put topSnakes = topSnakes.sort instead?

Comment: Yes, @RachelDockter, that is what you should put. Always make sure the variable names match up!

Comment: @RachelDockter no, its typo as js is typesafe sorry

Comment: @JHecht nope, topSnakes will be created in that moment, making Rachels whole code useless. Its just a snakes != Snakes thing

Comment: Ah, gotta love capitalizations!

Comment: i changed it to topSnakes = topSnakes.sort and its running, theres only 3 items in the leaderboard list but all the values are undefined like kill: undefined. and im not sure why :/

Comment: ok if i take out the first for loop and put topSnakes=snakes.sort instead, it wont work as snakes isnt an array its an object so snakes.sort isnt a function

Comment: @Rachel: but youre saying that snakes is an array ( in your first code block)

Comment: i think its an array in an object, so its declares as = {} instead of = []