# filter data and map the only received data

Tags: javascript, angular

I am facing a problem.

```
var arr = ['VBH', 'KTL', 'PVC', 'IF & AF', 'BC', 'CC&HC', 'UBS', 'FAD&DVD'];
var obj = [
             {"materialTypeID":9,"name":"","abbreviation":"UBS","count":1,"duns":0,"plantId":0},
             {"materialTypeID":18,"name":null,"abbreviation":"PVC","count":1,"duns":0,"plantId":0},
             {"materialTypeID":7,"name":"","abbreviation":"FAD&DVD","count":4,"duns":0,"plantId":0}
          ];
```

and I want the result in sorting format as arr variable shows such as VBH object or KTL object if they found.

```
[       
{"materialTypeID":18,"name":null,"abbreviation":"PVC","count":1,"duns":0,"plantId":0},
{"materialTypeID":9,"name":"","abbreviation":"UBS","count":1,"duns":0,"plantId":0},
{"materialTypeID":7,"name":"","abbreviation":"FAD&DVD","count":4,"duns":0,"plantId":0}
]
```

In java script, I want to implement.

Thanks,

Comment: provide code sample of what you have tried so far

Comment: from your question its not clear how do you want to sort the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the `arr` and use filter to get the element from the `obj`. `filter` will return a new array, check if the length of this new array is more than 0 , then use `push` to put the element

```js
var arr = ['VBH', 'KTL', 'PVC', 'IF & AF', 'BC', 'CC&HC', 'UBS', 'FAD&DVD']
var obj = [{
  "materialTypeID": 9,
  "name": "",
  "abbreviation": "UBS",
  "count": 1,
  "duns": 0,
  "plantId": 0
}, {
  "materialTypeID": 18,
  "name": null,
  "abbreviation": "PVC",
  "count": 1,
  "duns": 0,
  "plantId": 0
}, {
  "materialTypeID": 7,
  "name": "",
  "abbreviation": "FAD&DVD",
  "count": 4,
  "duns": 0,
  "plantId": 0
}]

let sortedArray = [];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  let getElem = obj.filter(function(items) {
    return items.abbreviation === item

  })
  if (getElem.length > 0) {
    sortedArray.push(getElem[0])
  }

})

console.log(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to sort by decreasing materialTypeID.

Your problem has already been resolved there : [Javascript object list sorting by object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466356/javascript-object-list-sorting-by-object-property)

```
obj.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return b.materialTypeID - a.materialTypeID;
})
```