# Javascript sort an array of objects based on numeric key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
var data = [
 {
   title: 'Shirt',
   position: 3
 },
 {
   title: 'Ball',
   position: 1,
 }
]
```

How could I sort it for use in a `for loop` like this.

```
for(var i in data) {

}
```

I tried:

```
for(var i in data | orderBy:'position')
```

But that is angular so normal Javascript it doesn't work.

I'm thinking their must be some way to sort the array before looping through it, or adding a filter to the loop, not sure which is the best way.

Comment: does this post answer your query?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466356/javascript-object-list-sorting-by-object-property

Comment: Why do you want to use a `for in` loop? Why not `sort`, whose abstract sorting rules are much easier to implement than your own custom sorting function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> But that is angular so normal Javascript it doesn't work.

Simply you can use JavaScript [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function. It will work in Angular(TypeScript) also.

**Note:** When sorting numbers, you can simply use the **compact comparison**:

> `myArray.sort((n1,n2) => n1 - n2);`

```js
var data = [{
    title: 'Shirt',
    position: 3
  },
  {
    title: 'Ball',
    position: 1,
  }
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.position - b.position;
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.prototype.sort` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) and pass the compare function as you want:

```js
var data = [
 {
   title: 'Shirt',
   position: 3
 },
 {
   title: 'Ball',
   position: 1,
 },
 // add for actually seeing the correct result
 {
   title: 'Cake',
   position: 2,
 }
];

function compareFunction(a,b){
  if(a.position > b.position)
    return 1;
  else
    return -1;
}

data.sort(compareFunction);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arr.sort([compareFunction]).

If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b, i.e. a comes first.

If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.

If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a, i.e. b comes first.

compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

For Example -

```
     myarray.sort((a,b) => {
       if(a.position > b.position)
        return 1
        else
        return -1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bubble sort approach:

```js
var data = [{
    title: 'Shirt',
    position: 3
  },
  {
    title: 'Ball',
    position: 1,
  },
  {
    title: "h",
    position: 0
  }
]

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  for (let j = 0; j < data.length - 1; j++) {
    if (data[j].position > data[j + 1].position) {
      var first = data[j]
      var second = data[j + 1]
      data[j] = second;
      data[j + 1] = first;

    }

  }

console.log(data)
```