# data grouping based on key value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am having an array of values like this

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Dhanush",
    "clientName": "Thor Odin",
    "id": "Client 1",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 86,
    "lastModified": "22/1/2022",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-1",
        "goalName": "Retirement1",
        "goalAmount": 10000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "22/1/2022",
        "score": 99
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-2",
        "goalName": "Save For Child Education",
        "goalAmount": 70000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "55/45",
        "lastModified": "5/12/2023",
        "score": 72
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Dhanush",
    "clientName": "Steve Rogers",
    "id": "Client 2",
    "goalName": "Save for Investment",
    "goalAmount": 67000,
    "goals": 1,
    "score": 70,
    "lastModified": "22/1/2022",
    "equityFixedIncome": "60/40"
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Dhanush",
    "clientName": "Wanda Vision",
    "id": "Client 3",
    "goals": 0,
    "score": 0,
    "lastModified": "",
    "equityFixedIncome": ""
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Dhanush",
    "clientName": "Tony Stark",
    "id": "Client 4",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 29,
    "lastModified": "27/10/2019",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-4",
        "goalName": "Education Loan",
        "goalAmount": 500,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "27/10/2019",
        "score": 29
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-5",
        "goalName": "House Loan",
        "goalAmount": 23000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "30/70",
        "lastModified": "16/6/2022",
        "score": 29
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Joe",
    "clientName": "Hack Eye",
    "id": "Client 5",
    "goalName": "Save For World Tour",
    "goalAmount": 400000,
    "goals": 1,
    "score": 74,
    "lastModified": "",
    "equityFixedIncome": "60/40"
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Joe",
    "clientName": "Nick Fury",
    "id": "Client 6",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 44,
    "lastModified": "9/3/2022",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-7",
        "goalName": "To Build A Workspace",
        "goalAmount": 42340,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "9/3/2022",
        "score": 60
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-8",
        "goalName": "Cloud Examination",
        "goalAmount": 8730,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "30/70",
        "lastModified": "9/11/2021",
        "score": 29
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Joe",
    "clientName": "Star Lord",
    "id": "Client 7",
    "goalName": "Save For Child Education",
    "goalAmount": 400000,
    "goals": 1,
    "score": 93,
    "lastModified": "",
    "equityFixedIncome": "55/45"
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Rohan",
    "advisorName": "Pal",
    "clientName": "Thanos",
    "id": "Client 8",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 3,
    "score": 29,
    "lastModified": "2/11/2019",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-10",
        "goalName": "Relocation Expense Goal",
        "goalAmount": 400000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "22/78",
        "lastModified": "2/11/2019",
        "score": 29
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-11",
        "goalName": "Save for to buy bike",
        "goalAmount": 400000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "50/50",
        "lastModified": "1/1/2020",
        "score": 29
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-12",
        "goalName": "Save For Education",
        "goalAmount": 400000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "65/35",
        "lastModified": "9/5/2022",
        "score": 29
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Rohan",
    "advisorName": "Pal",
    "clientName": "Ego",
    "id": "Client 9",
    "goalName": "Save For Education",
    "goalAmount": 400000,
    "goals": 1,
    "score": 72,
    "lastModified": "",
    "equityFixedIncome": "65/35"
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Rohan",
    "advisorName": "Pal",
    "clientName": "Bruce Banner",
    "id": "Client 10",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 98,
    "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-14",
        "goalName": "Car Loan",
        "goalAmount": 23000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
        "score": 99
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-15",
        "goalName": "Bike Loan",
        "goalAmount": 4600,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "30/70",
        "lastModified": "9/11/2021",
        "score": 96
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Rohan",
    "advisorName": "Dhanush",
    "clientName": "Bruce Banner",
    "id": "Client 11",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 98,
    "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-14",
        "goalName": "Car Loan",
        "goalAmount": 23000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
        "score": 99
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-15",
        "goalName": "Bike Loan",
        "goalAmount": 4600,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "30/70",
        "lastModified": "9/11/2021",
        "score": 96
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Dhanush",
    "clientName": "Bruce Banner",
    "id": "Client 12",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 98,
    "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-14",
        "goalName": "Car Loan",
        "goalAmount": 23000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
        "score": 99
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-15",
        "goalName": "Bike Loan",
        "goalAmount": 4600,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "30/70",
        "lastModified": "9/11/2021",
        "score": 96
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Suresh Murugaiyan",
    "advisorName": "Loki",
    "clientName": "Yondu",
    "id": "Client 13",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 98,
    "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-14",
        "goalName": "Car Loan",
        "goalAmount": 23000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "9/10/2018",
        "score": 99
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-15",
        "goalName": "Bike Loan",
        "goalAmount": 4600,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "30/70",
        "lastModified": "9/11/2021",
        "score": 96
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "managerName": "Nikolai",
    "advisorName": "Dhanush",
    "clientName": "Thor Odin",
    "id": "Client 1",
    "goalName": "",
    "goalAmount": "",
    "goals": 2,
    "score": 86,
    "lastModified": "22/1/2022",
    "equityFixedIncome": "",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-1",
        "goalName": "Retirement1",
        "goalAmount": 10000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "60/40",
        "lastModified": "22/1/2022",
        "score": 99
      },
      {
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "clientName": "",
        "id": "goal-2",
        "goalName": "Save For Child Education",
        "goalAmount": 70000,
        "goals": "",
        "equityFixedIncome": "55/45",
        "lastModified": "5/12/2023",
        "score": 72
      }
    ]
  }
]

----------
```

By using the below function

```
const data = [{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Dhanush","clientName":"Thor Odin","id":"Client 1","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":86,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-1","goalName":"Retirement1","goalAmount":10000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"22/1/2022","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-2","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":70000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"55/45","lastModified":"5/12/2023","score":72}]},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Dhanush","clientName":"Steve Rogers","id":"Client 2","goalName":"Save for Investment","goalAmount":67000,"goals":1,"score":70,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"60/40"},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Dhanush","clientName":"Wanda Vision","id":"Client 3","goals":0,"score":0,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":""},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Dhanush","clientName":"Tony Stark","id":"Client 4","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":29,"lastModified":"27/10/2019","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-4","goalName":"Education Loan","goalAmount":500,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"27/10/2019","score":29},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-5","goalName":"House Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"16/6/2022","score":29}]},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Joe","clientName":"Hack Eye","id":"Client 5","goalName":"Save For World Tour","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":74,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40"},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Joe","clientName":"Nick Fury","id":"Client 6","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":44,"lastModified":"9/3/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-7","goalName":"To Build A Workspace","goalAmount":42340,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/3/2022","score":60},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-8","goalName":"Cloud Examination","goalAmount":8730,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":29}]},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Joe","clientName":"Star Lord","id":"Client 7","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":93,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"55/45"},{"managerName":"Rohan","advisorName":"Pal","clientName":"Thanos","id":"Client 8","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":3,"score":29,"lastModified":"2/11/2019","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-10","goalName":"Relocation Expense Goal","goalAmount":400000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"22/78","lastModified":"2/11/2019","score":29},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-11","goalName":"Save for to buy bike","goalAmount":400000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"50/50","lastModified":"1/1/2020","score":29},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-12","goalName":"Save For Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"65/35","lastModified":"9/5/2022","score":29}]},{"managerName":"Rohan","advisorName":"Pal","clientName":"Ego","id":"Client 9","goalName":"Save For Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":72,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"65/35"},{"managerName":"Rohan","advisorName":"Pal","clientName":"Bruce Banner","id":"Client 10","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]},{"managerName":"Rohan","advisorName":"Dhanush","clientName":"Bruce Banner","id":"Client 11","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Dhanush","clientName":"Bruce Banner","id":"Client 12","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]},{"managerName":"Suresh Murugaiyan","advisorName":"Loki","clientName":"Yondu","id":"Client 13","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]},{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"Dhanush","clientName":"Thor Odin","id":"Client 1","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":86,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-1","goalName":"Retirement1","goalAmount":10000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"22/1/2022","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-2","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":70000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"55/45","lastModified":"5/12/2023","score":72}]}]

function groupByManager(val){
    const
    nodOrder = 
      { managerName: '',  advisorName: '', clientName: '', id: ''
      , goalName: ''   ,  goalAmount: '',  goals: '',      score: ''
      , lastModified: '', equityFixedIncome: ''
      } 
  , levels = 
      { managerName: { arr: null, val: '' }
      , advisorName: { arr: null, val: '' }
      , clientName:  { arr: null }
      }
  , resultData = []
    ;

    val.forEach( ({ managerName, advisorName, ...otherProps }) => 
    {
    let
      row_0 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, { managerName })
    , row_1 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, { advisorName })
    , row_2 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, otherProps )
      ;

    if (levels.managerName.val !== managerName )
      {

      levels.managerName.val = managerName 
      levels.managerName.arr = row_0.subRows = []
      levels.advisorName.val = ''
      resultData.push( row_0 )
      }

    if (levels.advisorName.val !== advisorName )
      {
      levels.advisorName.val = advisorName 
      levels.advisorName.arr = row_1.subRows = []
      levels.managerName.arr.push( row_1 )
      }

  
    levels.clientName.arr = (otherProps.subRows) ? (row_2.subRows = []) : null
    levels.advisorName.arr.push( row_2 )
  
    if (otherProps.subRows) 
      {
      otherProps.subRows.forEach( subRow => 
        {
        let sRow = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, subRow )
        levels.clientName.arr.push( sRow )
        })
      }
    })
  return resultData
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByManager(data)))
```

I am converting the data into the format like this - https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-table-expansion-1t77ks?file=/src/data/table-data.json:0-9490. Which is then used in the `@tastack-react-table`. You can see the demo of the application here - https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-table-expansion-1t77ks?file=/src/App.js

In the above code conversion, the grouping works properly but only if the values occur in the correct order. That means in the first object you can see the `managerName` is  `Nikolai` the same value is repeated for the next `7` objects. After that, a different `managerName` as `Rohan` is repeated for the next `3` objects.

Here `managerName` as  `Nikolai` has formed a group, after that `managerName` `Rohan` has formed another group and again if `managerName`   `Nikolai` repeats means it forms a separate group, instead of not get grouped with already available one.

You can get a better understanding by seeing the below image. You can see the name `Nikolai` appears again. It doesn't form a group with the one already grouped.

[image]

Also the `advisorName` also not grouped properly. It does the same error.

[image]

I tried to solve this, but I don't know where I am making mistake, please help me to resolve this one.

**Expected Output**

```
[{"managerName":"Nikolai","advisorName":"","id":"","clientName":"","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":"","score":"","lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"advisorName":"Dhanush","managerName":"","id":"","clientName":"","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":"","score":"","lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 1","clientName":"Thor Odin","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":86,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-1","goalName":"Retirement1","goalAmount":10000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"22/1/2022","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-2","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":70000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"55/45","lastModified":"5/12/2023","score":72}]},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 2","clientName":"Steve Rogers","goalName":"Save for Investment","goalAmount":67000,"goals":1,"score":70,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"60/40"},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 3","clientName":"Wanda Vision","goals":0,"score":0,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":""},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 4","clientName":"Tony Stark","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":29,"lastModified":"27/10/2019","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-4","goalName":"Education Loan","goalAmount":500,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"27/10/2019","score":29},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-5","goalName":"House Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"16/6/2022","score":29}]},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 11","clientName":"Bruce Banner","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 12","clientName":"Bruce Banner","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 1","clientName":"Thor Odin","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":86,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-1","goalName":"Retirement1","goalAmount":10000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"22/1/2022","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-2","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":70000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"55/45","lastModified":"5/12/2023","score":72}]}]},{"advisorName":"Joe","managerName":"","id":"","clientName":"","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":"","score":"","lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 5","clientName":"Hack Eye","goalName":"Save For World Tour","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":74,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40"},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 6","clientName":"Nick Fury","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":44,"lastModified":"9/3/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-7","goalName":"To Build A Workspace","goalAmount":42340,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/3/2022","score":60},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-8","goalName":"Cloud Examination","goalAmount":8730,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":29}]},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 7","clientName":"Star Lord","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":93,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"55/45"}]}]},{"managerName":"Suresh Murugaiyan","advisorName":"","id":"","clientName":"","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":"","score":"","lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"advisorName":"Loki","managerName":"","id":"","clientName":"","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":"","score":"","lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 13","clientName":"Yondu","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]}]}]},{"managerName":"Rohan","advisorName":"","id":"","clientName":"","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":"","score":"","lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"advisorName":"Pal","managerName":"","id":"","clientName":"","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":"","score":"","lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 8","clientName":"Thanos","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":3,"score":29,"lastModified":"2/11/2019","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-10","goalName":"Relocation Expense Goal","goalAmount":400000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"22/78","lastModified":"2/11/2019","score":29},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-11","goalName":"Save for to buy bike","goalAmount":400000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"50/50","lastModified":"1/1/2020","score":29},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-12","goalName":"Save For Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"65/35","lastModified":"9/5/2022","score":29}]},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 9","clientName":"Ego","goalName":"Save For Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":72,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"65/35"},{"advisorName":"","managerName":"","id":"Client 10","clientName":"Bruce Banner","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":98,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-14","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":99},{"managerName":"","advisorName":"","clientName":"","id":"goal-15","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":"","equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":96}]}]}]}]
```

Comment: You could [sort the list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466356/sorting-objects-by-property-values) by managerName.

Comment: Yes, but is there any way we could do this without that?

Comment: Yes, group the objects by manager name using reduce ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)).

Comment: but, you see the sub level ```advisorName``` has also not grouped properly

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the above example

Comment: hi, I have added the expected output. Sry I am not able to format the data, because of character limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `managerName` first, then, for each manager, group their advisors by `advisorName`.

- Define a generic helper function that takes an array and a property name to group the items by its value. Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the key is the property value (eg manager name) and the value is the list of objects having this value. After that, using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object#asign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), it would return the grouped pairs as an array of objects each is a template of `row` with the property (key) and subRows (value).
- Having an array of objects like the one you shared, we first need to group them by `managerName` using the above helper. After that, iterating over each manager using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), we need to group its advisors in the `subRows` using the above helper as well but by the `advisorName` this time.

```
const _groupBy = (arr = [], prop) => {
  const row = {
    managerName: "",
    advisorName: "",
    clientName: "",
    id: "",
    goalName: "",
    goalAmount: "",
    goals: "",
    score: "",
    lastModified: "",
    equityFixedIncome: ""
  };
  const map = arr.reduce(
    (map, { [prop]: propToGroupBy, ...props }) =>
      map.set(propToGroupBy, [
        ...(map.get(propToGroupBy) ?? []),
        { [prop]: "", ...props }
      ]),
    new Map()
  );
  return [...map.entries()].map(([propToGroupBy, subRows]) =>
    Object.assign({}, row, {
      [prop]: propToGroupBy,
      subRows
    })
  );
};

const groupData = (arr = []) => {
  const managerList = _groupBy(arr, "managerName");
  managerList.forEach((manager) => {
    manager.subRows = _groupBy(manager.subRows, "advisorName");
  });
  return managerList;
};
```