# angular 17 not orderby when push to array inside Accordion

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17

I use Angular 17, ng-bootstrap. When I push new item to array, new item added last array but item alway show first item in html.

Array index can run success if outside ngbAccordion (bootstrap).

Help me? The array should be ordered by index when push new item to array inside ngbAccordion.

this code:

home.html

```html
    <div ngbAccordion class=" mt-3 accordion-bordered">
      @for (item of array2; track item; let idx = $index) {
      <div ngbAccordionItem [collapsed]="true">
        <h2 ngbAccordionHeader class="bg-f7">
          <button ngbAccordionButton>{{item}}</button>
    
        </h2>
        <div ngbAccordionCollapse>
          <div ngbAccordionBody>
            <ng-template>
              <div *ngFor="let e of array;trackBy: identify">
                {{e.id}} - {{e.name}}
             </div>
             <button (click)="foo()">foo</button>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      }
    </div>
```

home.ts

```js
    array2 = [
        { id: 1, name: 'bill' },
        { id: 2, name: 'bob' },
        { id: 3, name: 'billy' },
      ];
      array = [
        { id: 1, name: 'bill' },
        { id: 2, name: 'bob' },
        { id: 3, name: 'billy' },
      ];
    
      foo() {
        this.array.push({ id: 4, name: '44444' });
      }
```

result: `{ id: 4, name: '44444' }` is always first array in HTML

Comment: If you want the array to be sorted, you need to call `sort` on it... See [Sorting objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2466356/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466356/sorting-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: i think error something. Not sort. when click button, it added item to last array, but html is show first item.

Comment: Why are you mixing the `*ngFor` and `@for` syntaxes?

Comment: i try code. ngfor same @for.

Comment: To insert into an array you can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Wrap you `ngFor` into `div`. It's a bug on ng-bootstrap side.